# How to flash Lenovo Yoga Book that doesn't boot into the OS?

Tags: stock-android, unbricking, lenovo-yoga

I've acquired a Lenovo Yoga Book (YB1-X90F) that doesn't boot into the OS. I can access the bootloader and recovery environment.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've followed the guide over at [XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/yoga-book-yb1-x90f-android-how-to-flash-back-to-stock-rom-6-0-1-downgrade.3709930/#post-74627585) that uses Intel Platform Flash Tool, but I get errors straight away. Another person has the same problem--2nd to last poster.:

```
02/20/22 15:54:20.155  ERROR  : [Port 1/7] Command `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Platform Flash Tool Lite\fastboot.exe" "-s"
"YETIDD2E4EC8" "flashing" "unlock"` failed
02/20/22 15:54:20.155  ERROR  : [Port 1/7] Flash failed (Command type: Fastboot)
```

I've also installed **Minimal ADB and Fastboot** but I don't know what I'm doing.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot devices
YETIDD2E4EC8    fastboot

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>adb devices List of
devices attached

C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>
```

The ROM I got (YB1-X90F_USR_S000196_1611040312_WW06_BP_ROW-flashfiles.zip) from some random site includes what looks like some info or installation steps in the .zip, but even with Word auto-translation into Chinglish, I don't understand what is being said.

Original: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1oSLs0o5x1UMwNULU33W8f150-CXcP8a0/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=105608869882772012095&rtpof=true&sd=true

Translated: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rspmYkqhzcx0Muu3QoFPmjWz9mRsO6CE/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=105608869882772012095&rtpof=true&sd=true

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you select "Wide data" or "Wipe cache" in recovery?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry, forgot to mention that. It completes the wipes but doesn't do anything to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I ran 'flash_update_from_user.json

Just waiting for the battery to charge to 30% to hopefully enable the Halo Keyboard.

Here are the files needed in case other links void in the future: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gD9FyA03GbLZ7ZcjkyMDlhVPs4_em2rY?usp=sharing